# Проблема с NuGet при использовании Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nuget

Программа использует следующие технологии: .NET Framework 4.7.2 + WPF   + Entity Framework Core, для всего установлены все необходимые NuGet пакеты. Проект залит на гитхаб. Все работает корректно.  Однако, если скачать архивом проект с гита то ловлю ошибку, которая говорит, что не получилось установить Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI. После скачивания проекта, удаляю и заново скачиваю этот пакет - все работает. Подскажите, что это такое?

P.S. нашел похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178092/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-sqlclient), но там была проблема именно в том,что не могли загрузить пакет. А моя проблема в том,что он загружен, но после скачивания с гитхаб работает некорректно.